# How to change openldap password as user on CentOS?

Tags: authentication, centos7, openldap

#### Original

I am running an openldap-2.4.40 authentication system and would a user to be able to change his password on hisown. With a dynamic configuration (meaning I am not using `slapd.conf` for configuration but the files in the `cn=config` directory), I tried changing the password with

```
ldappasswd -x -D "uid=<my_user>,ou=Users,dc=<some>,dc=<dc>" -W -A -S
```

This prompts me for my old password (twice) and for the new one and then asks for the LDAP password terminating with the error messag: `ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)`.

1. Why does the command ask me for the LDAP password. The standard user should not know that password
2. Why does the program terminate with invalid credentials?

In my `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config.ldif` I have the following settings for `olcAccess`:

```
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage by * none
```

What do I need to do so that the user is able to change his password?

#### Edit

Responding to the answer of Simon Schürg I add the contents of `/etc/pam.d/passwd`:

```
auth       include      system-auth
account    include      system-auth
password   substack     system-auth
-password   optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so use_authtok
password   substack     postlogin
```

If I change the password with `passwd` everything works just fine and I can log myself in with the new password, but only on the machine with the LDAP server running. I cannot login on all other machines ("the LDAP clients").

#### Edit2

An `ldapsearch` on a user or group on the server and client machines provides the same output. However, `authconfig --test` output differs if performed as root or as a user:

Performed as root:

```
nss_ldap is enabled
 LDAP+TLS is disabled
 LDAP server = "ldap://10.0.0.254"
 LDAP base DN = "dc=example,dc=com"

pam_ldap is enabled
 LDAP+TLS is disabled
 LDAP server = "ldap://10.0.0.254"
 LDAP base DN = "dc=example,dc=com"
 LDAP schema = "rfc2307"
```

Performed as user:

```
nss_ldap is enabled
 LDAP+TLS is disabled
 LDAP server = ""
 LDAP base DN = ""

pam_ldap is enabled
 LDAP+TLS is disabled
 LDAP server = ""
 LDAP base DN = ""
 LDAP schema = "rfc2307"
```

If any information for the answer is missing please let me know and I will edit the question and provide you with the information.

Comment: Your `authconfig --test` results show the root user is configured to see LDAP and the regular is not.  Is this on the LDAP server or on a client machine?  You need your clients to allow local login (so that root access is preserved) and to allow LDAP authenticated login.

Answer (score 4):

If you enable LDAP authentication globally through PAM and configure */etc/pam.d/passwd*, users can change their own LDAP password through the *passwd* command like it's common for local Unix accounts.

I expect you are already able to log in with ldap users.

In order to allow password changes with the passwd command yout you have to edit */etc/pam.d/passwd* and add

```
password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so
```

------ edit ------

Instead of editing the configuration files manually you could also use *authconfig* to configure ldap on the centos client.
The following command configures LDAP authentication in a way that users can change their password with the common `passwd` command.

```
authconfig \
  --enableldap \
  --enableldapauth \
  --ldapserver='ldap://example.com/' \
  --ldapbasedn='dc=example,dc=com' \
  --update
```

Maybe you want also use the following flags to preserve local authentication and auto creation of non-existing home directories at login.

```
  --enablemkhomedir \ 
  --enableshadow \
  --enablelocauthorize \
  --passalgo=sha256 \
```

After the previous command run `authconfig --test` to verify the settings.
Check the following parts of the output:

```
nss_ldap is enabled
 LDAP+TLS is disabled
 LDAP server = "ldap://example.com/"
 LDAP base DN = "dc=example,dc=com"

pam_unix is always enabled
 shadow passwords are enabled
 password hashing algorithm is sha256

pam_ldap is enabled
 LDAP+TLS is disabled
 LDAP server = "ldap://example.com/"
 LDAP base DN = "dc=example,dc=com"
 LDAP schema = "rfc2307"

pam_mkhomedir or pam_oddjob_mkhomedir is enabled (umask=0077)
Always authorize local users is enabled ()
```

Changing password for users is now simple as:

```
ldapuser@centos ~ % passwd
Changing password for user ldapuser.
(current) LDAP Password: 
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
ldapuser@centos ~ %
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in a direction I haven't looked at yet. Howver, I still need a little help. (See question edit above).

Comment: Thank you for your the edit of your answer! Without running the `authconfig` command I have in `authconfig --test` the exact same output as you have listed in your answer. The `passwd` changes the password just like you printed in your answer, but I still cannot login the other machines with the new password but only the old one. Do you have any idea what still míght be going wrong here?

Comment: the authconfig --test lead me to a possible issue as stated in the `Edit2` part of my qustion above. Also is there a way of running `authconfig` without permanently loosing all current configurations? Like, some way of backing up the current configuration?

Comment: For `authconfig` the `--backup` option is available, IIRC